# Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, hosting, vite

I am trying to host an app on Heroku (React + Vite), but after the build succeeds the hosting fails because:

"Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling."

What does this mean and how can I go about resolving this? Do I need to have something specific in my vite.config.js?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio-website",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "start": "node main.jsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@glidejs/glide": "3.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "rollup": "^2.79.1",
    "sass": "^1.54.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.17.1"
  }
}
```

Procfile:

```
web: npm run dev --port $PORT
```

static.json:

```
{
    "routes": {
      "/**": "index.html"
    }
  }
```

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

Comment: If the build succeeds, this is a runtime issue. Please [edit] your question and add your `package.json` and, if you have one, your `Procfile` so we can see how you've instructed Heroku to run your application.

Comment: Ok updated! Thank you for the response.

Comment: It looks like Vite is a front-end framework. Do you also have back-end code, or is this purely a front-end application?

Comment: Thank you-- this is my first time hosting a site and didn't even realize I needed some sort of back end element to compile, bundle, render, etc. Im transitioning this project to Next.js and Vercel now.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having a front-end-only application if that's all you need. But if that's what you're doing, I suggest you host it elsewhere. That's not what Heroku is designed for.